# Sabre XML writer's output is a plain string

Tags: php, xml

I am using the Sabre XML writer library.

I am trying the example from the site itself:

```
 $writer = new Sabre\Xml\Writer();
        $writer->openMemory();
        $writer->namespaceMap = [
            'http://example.org/' => 'e',
        ];

        $writer->startElement('{http://example.org/}root');
        $writer->write([
    '{http://example.org/ns}title' => 'Foundation',
    '{http://example.org/ns}author' => 'Isaac Asimov',]);

        $writer->endElement();
        echo $writer->outputMemory();
```

I am expecting this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<e:root>
    <e:title>Foundation</e:title>
    <e:author>Isaac Asimov</e:author>
</e:root>
```

but instead I got a plain string:

```
FoundationIsaac Asimov
```

I have  tried the XML reader functions and they work just fine, so the package is correctly instealled.

Any help?

Comment: View the source of the page. What's it look like? Perhaps it is being interpreted as HTML elements... That said, I think unknown elements are assumed to be block level, and so the words would appear under each other

Comment: @JustCarty Exactly I forgot to use headers...

Comment: Nice, glad to have helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use headers:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @JustCarty You have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer.